# Xbox-live Sign-in issues with IL2CPP scripting backend

Tags: unity-game-engine, xbox-live

I signed up for the Creators program and am now testing the Xbox Live plugin for Unity.

For testing I only want to sign in a user.

Using .Net as scripting backend everything works just fine and I can see a fake user signed in in unity and I can also use the sandbox on Windows and on the Xbox.

Once I switch to the scripting backend IL2CPP I can still see the fake user if I run the scene in Unity. However, if I build I get a FileNotFound exception for the .csproj that was obviously not generated as Unity generates a .vcxproj file instead (using IL2CPP backend). The build however is still creating a VS Project. I can manually rename the  file in the XBoxLivePostProcessing.cs which removes the exception but does not make the build work.

Opening the build in Visual Studio the XBoxServices.config file has not been added to the project. If I run the build everything looks normal but no user is being signed in (it shows "Gamertag" and "Gamerscore"). Adding the XBoxServices.config and setting "Content" to "True" will cause the build to crash once executed at a line that says NOT_IMPLEMENTED_ICALL. Also there is an error which complains that the XBoxServices.config file has no valid XML structure, which is weird as the file is set to be a text file and does not contain any XML, am I missing something here? Can I somehow tell VS to not interpret the file as XML file?

More importantly is there a way to fix the build issue in Unity? Does anyone have an idea what might be wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: The XBOX live API is likely using an API not yet implemeted on the IL2CPP side or this is simply a bug. File for a bug report from the Editor

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like I simply had an old version of the Xbox Live plugin. The full IL2CPP support was added in version 1801.